# goto and junping loop by loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, goto

im a new programmer and user here.
I don't want to use goto in my code because I don't want to be called " a bad programmer".
I need your experience to get rid of that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int control = 1;
    char a[50], harf[5][10];
    a[0] = 65 + rand() % 26;
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            a[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;
        else
            a[i] = 97 + rand() % 26;
    come:
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    a[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;    goto come;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[i] = 97 + rand() % 26;    goto come;
                }
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        cout << a[i]<<" ";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9IHb.png)

Comment: StackOverflow may not be the best venue for this. Perhaps SoftwareEngineering is. Anyway, I recommend pulling the inner for loop into its own function.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals instead of their decimal ASCII encodings.  For example, replace 65 with `'A'`.  Makes the code easier to read also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a function, replace your "goto" with "j = -1;"

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `come` block (the inner for-cycle) with a function. Then, instead of `goto come`, you call `come()` (assuming the name of the function is "come").

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
come:
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j])
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                a[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;    goto come;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = 97 + rand() % 26;    goto come;
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
```

with

```
int loop=0;
do
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j])
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                a[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = 97 + rand() % 26;
            }
            loop=1;
            break;
        }
        else
            loop=0;
    }
}while(loop);
```

This is a more general sort of solution than some other answers. It's based on realizing that when you find a match `(a[i] == a[j])` you just want to run the main `for` loop again, from the top. (You can achive the same result by setting `j` to -1, but that won't work in all situations, and certainly not if `j` needs to be `unsigned`)